# Ubuntu blank login screen after installing kubuntu 15.04 with plasma, only guest login is possible

Tags: lightdm, plasma

I was using ubuntu 15.04 above that I installed kubuntu with plasma desktop. After reboot I can not see my login screen. all I can see is blank screen. If I press enter it automatically logging me into guest session. and even there I cant switch account.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and login with your username and password.

Then, run the following commands:

```
cd /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
ls
```

This should list all the files in this directory.

You should only have one file in this directory named `50-unity-greeter.conf`, this file should contain the following:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Delete any other files in this directory using the `rm` command with `sudo`.

Then, restart lightdm using the following command:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```